Could it be that the head of a noun phrase is not a noun, but a nominal?
The textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 22:

The textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 24:


(1) the photographs of their dog that they had brought with them
As far as I understood, the passage above can be reformulated the following way:
The noun “photographs” is the head of the nominal “photographs of their dog”.
The nominal “photographs of their dog” is the head of the nominal "photographs of their dog that they had brought with them".
The nominal "photographs of their dog that they had brought with them" is the head of the noun phrase "the photographs of their dog that they had brought with them".

Did I understand correctly that:
"Photographs" can be called a noun or a nominal, but not a noun phrase.
“Photographs of their dog” is a nominal, but not a noun phrase.
"Photographs of their dog that they had brought with them" is a nominal, but not a noun phrase.
"The photographs of their dog that they had brought with them" is a noun phrase, but not a nominal.

Did I understand correctly that:
It's incorrect to say the head of (1) is the noun "photographs".
It's only correct to say the head of (1) is the nominal "photographs of their dog that they had brought with them".

Did they bring the photographs or the dog? or both?

The tree diagram on p332 should answer your question.

Whether or not to call something a nominal or an NP depends on context. If it were used on its own photographs could be head noun, nominal, and NP, depending on the layer of analysis.

Photographs are not needed.

For the noun phrase from CGEL, we could still say that photographs is the head of the NP as everything else is its dependent in one way or another. The rest is just the layered analysis of the ways in which those other items are its dependents.

To be clear, CGEL does differentiate between the intermediary heads and the ultimate head. So it would be incorrect to say that the head of each of the intermediary elements, in the layered analysis, is also the single noun at the head on the whole NP.

Head and ultimate head
We have seen that the head position can be filled by a noun, as in the
man, or a nominal, as in the old man. In the latter example, the
nominal itself has the noun man as head, and we will refer to this as
the ultimate head of the NP, i.e. the final head element in a line
running from the NP through any intermediate heads until we reach the
level of the word. (330)

This is, however, a term that is mainly used when disambiguation is needed. In discussions where the word head on its own suffices, ultimate does not always appear. For example in CGEL's discussion of proper names:

Proper nouns function as heads of proper names, but not all proper
names have proper nouns as their head: the heads of such proper names
as The United States of America, the Leeward Islands, the University
of Manchester, for example, are common nouns. (516)


From your answer, I inferred that in the diagram you posted, CGEL considers the noun "salary" as the head of EVERY of the six layers of the diagram (that is, not only as the head of the lowest layer "preposterous salary"). Am I right? Thanks.

@Loviii No. The head of each layer is the constituent labeled as "Head" in the diagram, but the ultimate head of the NP (in their terms)--i.e. the head of the head of the head of the..--is photographs.

@alphabet If you say the head of the whole NP "even all the preposterous salary from Lloyds that Bill gets" is not the noun "salary", but the nominal "all the preposterous salary from Lloyds that Bill gets", then you will also say that the head of the whole NP "the photographs of their dog that they had brought with them" is not the noun "photographs", but the nominal "photographs of their dog that they had brought with them". That means you disagree with DW256 who wrote: we could still say that "photographs" is the head of the whole NP. Did I understand you correctly? Thanks.
